# UIImage(named: ) returns nil in cocoapod library on ios 12.4-5

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, bundle, ios12

I have my Cocoapod library, In this library I access my images this way:

```
let bundle = Bundle(identifier: "com.mylib.mylib")
let image = UIImage(named: "image_name", in: bundle, compatibleWith: nil)
```

This works perfectly on devices 14.0 and above, but in IOS 12.4 this always returns the nil.
I tried other way to get bundle like this: `let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))`
result is same.

Interesting is that when I import library in project, from library project (as source code), it works without problem (on 12.4).

but when I try to import library from pod, it returns nil (only on 12.4). Also images from main bundle is not problem, it can display main bundle icons in my library.
I'm out of ideas of what can be the case..